# Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout SheetContent appears not from the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I need to show two different bottom sheets in one screen. I change the `sheetContent` of the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` dynamically using a `dialogType` state. I hide the `High` bottom sheet, change `dialogType` and show the `Short`. `Short` appears from the top of the previous bottom sheet, not from the bottom of the screen,
[you can see here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uNKy.gif)

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheet() {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var dialogType by remember { mutableStateOf<BottomSheetType>(BottomSheetType.None) }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            when (dialogType) {
                is BottomSheetType.High -> {
                    LazyColumn {
                        items(10) {
                            Text(text = "Item $it")
                        }

                        item {
                            Button(onClick = {
                                scope.launch {
                                    sheetState.hide()
                                    dialogType = BottomSheetType.Short
                                    sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text(text = "Short Bottom Sheet")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                is BottomSheetType.Short -> {
                    Text(text = "Item 1")
                }
                is BottomSheetType.None -> Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(1.dp))
            }
        }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    dialogType = BottomSheetType.High
                    scope.launch {
                        sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            ) {
                Text(text = "High Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}

sealed class BottomSheetType {
    object None : BottomSheetType()
    object High : BottomSheetType()
    object Short : BottomSheetType()
}
```

If add `sheetState.performFling(0.1f)` before `sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)`, `Short` bottom sheet appears correct.
*Compose version 1.1.0-beta01*

Comment: Hi Svitlana, I have the same issue in my app.  Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. Not just that, many other Composables in `Compose` are pre-built to incorporate default animations. The only thing you can do is read the docs to see if there is an overriding mechanism provided. Otherwise, you'll only chance is to look at the source code. Just `Ctrl` + `Click` on the name of the Composable and you'll see the source. You can copy-paste it, then modify per your needs. I don't think `ModalBottomSheetLayout` provides a default overriding mechanism, so that's pretty much your answer - It is the implemented behaviour. You'll need to modify the source and create a custom Composable.